# automatically open Rails generate migration file in editor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration, textmate, rails-generate

Is it possible to configure Rails so that after running `rails g migration name_of_migration`, it automatically opens that file in TextMate?

Comment: yeap, you can hack the source %)

Comment: If my solution is the right one, would you mind selecting it?

Answer (score 5):

You could create an alias with this:

```
alias last_migration='ls db/migrate/* | tail -n1 | xargs open -a "Textmate"'
```

and then run it from your terminal:

```
last_migration
```

Comment: I've to do add `*.rb` to the `ls` filter because it didn't worked for me:
`alias last_migration='ls db/migrate/*.rb | tail -n1 | xargs open -a "MyEditor"'`

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can generate migration in Textmate, using the following shortcut -

"Shift + Control + M"

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Do I need a special bundle or something?

Comment: you need the ruby on rails bundle